# MySQL query SELECT GREATEST int row VALUE beetween limits

Tags: mysql, select, comparison, range

I need to get the count of records in table where the value of the fileds: (`ps1,ps2,ps3,ps4,ps5,ps6,ps7,ps8,ps9,ps10`) between min and max `limits` is greatest. And to compare this value to an other filed value `d_max`.

**ex:**

```
SELECT count(*) FROM table WHERE d_max < 
{GREATEST one of (ps1,ps2,ps3,ps4,ps5,ps6,ps7,ps8,ps9,ps10) BEETWEEN 10 AND 20}
```

Please help.

Comment: Well, why don't you just adjust some answers / ideas here? Where is your effort? You don't even clarify enough, what you want to achieve. So you better stop downvoting the answers here, just because they don't fit your not clear needs.

Comment: @tombom - I think voting down requires 125 rep, so it's not the OP `:)`

Comment: @tombom, I'm the downvoter and I downvoted because the answers downvoted are incorrect. This is not a trivial question and it does not have a trivial answer. That's why a simple answer is `not useful` and thus should be downvoted.

Comment: @tombom, secondly, I think the OP posted a `good` question, A: he explains clearly what he wants B: he posts pseudo code of what he tried (and failed with) C: the question has a clear title and correct tags. The fact that OP is a beginner in SQL does not warrant your somewhat harsh comment. As for effort, the OP is obviously stuck what would you have him do if he does not know how to proceed, IMHO adding more words to the question is liable to make it worse, not better (never mind the minor typos).

Comment: @Johan Okay, my comment may have been a bit harsh (and wrong since one can't downvote with less than 125 rep, like halfer said). Sorry for that. And I didn't mind typos or whatever, noone is perfect, but for me it was not clear from start, what he really wants.

Answer (score 1):

Not pretty, but it should work:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (
  SELECT 
    t0.d_max
    , IFNULL(t1.ps1,0) as ps1, IFNULL(t2.ps2,0) as ps2
    , IFNULL(t3.ps3,0) as ps3, IFNULL(t4.ps4,0) as ps4
    , IFNULL(t5.ps5,0) as ps5, IFNULL(t6.ps6,0) as ps6
    , IFNULL(t7.ps7,0) as ps7, IFNULL(t8.ps8,0) as ps8
    , IFNULL(t9.ps9,0) as ps9, IFNULL(t10.ps10,0) as ps10
  FROM `table` t0
  LEFT JOIN `table` t1 ON (t0.id = t1.id AND t1.ps1 BETWEEN 10 AND 20)
  LEFT JOIN `table` t2 ON (t0.id = t2.id AND t2.ps2 BETWEEN 10 AND 20)
  LEFT JOIN `table` t3 ON (t0.id = t3.id AND t3.ps3 BETWEEN 10 AND 20)
  LEFT JOIN `table` t4 ON (t0.id = t4.id AND t4.ps4 BETWEEN 10 AND 20)
  LEFT JOIN `table` t5 ON (t0.id = t5.id AND t5.ps5 BETWEEN 10 AND 20)
  LEFT JOIN `table` t6 ON (t0.id = t6.id AND t6.ps6 BETWEEN 10 AND 20)
  LEFT JOIN `table` t7 ON (t0.id = t7.id AND t7.ps7 BETWEEN 10 AND 20)
  LEFT JOIN `table` t8 ON (t0.id = t8.id AND t8.ps8 BETWEEN 10 AND 20)
  LEFT JOIN `table` t9 ON (t0.id = t9.id AND t9.ps9 BETWEEN 10 AND 20)
  LEFT JOIN `table` t10 ON (t0.id = t10.id AND t10.ps10 BETWEEN 10 AND 20)
) s
WHERE s.d_max < GREATEST(s.ps1,s.ps2,s.ps3,s.ps4,s.ps5,s.ps6,s.ps7,s.ps8,s.ps9,s.ps10)
```

Note that this does require an explicit primary key to be set of this table, however if you're using InnoDB you should always use an explicit PK, or suffer serious performance issues.

**Edit**
See if the following construct would be faster....

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (
  SELECT 
    d_max
    ,CASE WHEN ps1 BETWEEN 10 AND 20 THEN ps1 ELSE 0 END AS ps1
    ,...
    ,CASE WHEN ps10 BETWEEN ..                           AS ps10
) s
WHERE s.d_max < GREATEST(s.ps1,s.ps2,s.ps3,s.ps4,s.ps5,s.ps6,s.ps7,s.ps8,s.ps9,s.ps10)
```

Comment: @Nick, see the updated answer and let me know if that's any faster.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE d_max < 
(SELECT GREATEST(col1, col2,....) FROM table_name WHERE column_name BETWEEN 10 AND 20;)
```

Comment: MAX(column_name) is not good because I need the max one from many fileds in each record
The range of(ps1,ps2,ps3,ps4,ps5,ps6,ps7,ps8,ps9,ps10) BEETWEEN 10 AND 20 with their greatest value must be compared with d_max

Comment: This still will not work, because you're only testing one column and you should be testing all ten of them.